On disjoint coverings in a locale
I am working in a constructive (non-LEM) setting below.
Let $X$ be a locale and let $\top = \bigvee_{i \in I} U_i$ be a covering in $X$. I think that at makes sense to call the covering disjoint if the map $\mathrm{Ouv}(X) \to \prod_{i \in I} \mathrm{Ouv}(U_i),\ U \mapsto (U \cap U_i)_{i \in I}$ is bijective (its inverse is then necessarily given by $\prod_{i \in I} \mathrm{Ouv}(U_i) \to \mathrm{Ouv}(X),\ (V_i)_{i \in I} \mapsto \bigvee_{i \in I} V_i$). This is equivalent to the fact that the embeddings $U_i{\downarrow} \to X$ exhibit $X$ as the coproduct of the $U_i{\downarrow}$ in the category of locales.
However with this definition it is not immediately obvious that if $f \colon Y \to X$ is a morphism of locales and $\top_X = \bigvee_{i \in I} U_i$ is a disjoint covering of $X$ then the covering $\top_Y = \bigvee_{i \in I} f^*(U_i)$ is a disjoint covering of $Y$ (or at least I don't see how).
If the index set $I$ is discrete (has decidable equality), I think I can show that the covering is disjoint if and only if for any two indices $i, j \in I$ with $i \neq j$ we have $U_i \wedge U_j = \bot$.
Since this condition refers only to pairwise intersections of the $U_i$ (and the constant $\bot$), which are preserved under morphisms of locales, this condition is obviously stable under morphisms of locales.
Is there a similar definition for disjoint coverings which refers only to the opens $U_i$ which works for arbitrary index sets in a constructive setting?
Note that if $X$ is the discrete locale associated with a set $A$ (i.e. $\mathrm{Ouv}(X) = \mathfrak{P}(A)$), then there is a perfectly reasonable constructive definition of disjoint coverings, namely a covering $A = \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ is disjoint if and only if for every $x \in A$ there exists a unique index $i \in I$ such that $x \in A_i$, and this condition is easily seen to be stable under pre-images.

Why doesn't the proof of the equivalence work for general $I$? Also, I would take $U_i \wedge U_j = \bot$ as the definition. This is common in lattice theory.

It is problematic for general index sets because of the condition $i \ne j$. It is better to use a condition that can smoothly handle the case $i = j$ without resorting to cases.

It is a bit doubtful to me whether the word "disjoint" is truly applicable when the indexing set itself is not decidable, but I believe your definition makes sense.
(It is basically the same condition that appears in the definition of lextensive category.)
Anyway, the trick appears to be to use $\Omega$-linearity of complete join semilattices to avoid definitions by cases.
Put another way, the fact that we can take joins of arbitrary subsets means that it is not necessary to give a completely exhaustive and mutually exclusive definition by cases!
For example, instead of
$$a (i) \wedge a (j) = \begin{cases}
a (i) & \text{if } i = j \\
\bot_A & \text{if } i \ne j
\end{cases}$$
(which fails to be exhaustive if we do not have either $i = j$ or $i \ne j$), we can think about
$$a (i) \wedge a (j) = \bigvee_{k \in \{ i \} \cap \{ j \}} a (k)$$
which certainly satisfies both of the requirements but remains well-defined even in the absence of decidability.
Let us apply this idea to the problem at hand.
Let $A$ be a frame, let $I$ be a set, and let $a : I \to A$ be a map.
For concreteness, let
$$A' = \{ x \in A^I : x (i) \le a (i) \}$$
and define $h : A \to A'$ by:
$$h (x) (i) = x \wedge a (i)$$
First, observe that we have the following adjointness for all $x \in A$ and all $y \in A'$:
$$\bigvee_{i \in I} y (i) \le x \text{ if and only if, for all } i \in I \text{, } y (i) \le x \wedge a (i)$$
Therefore, $h : A \to A'$ is an isomorphism if and only if, for all $x \in A$ and all $y \in A'$:
$$x \le \bigvee_{i \in I} y (i) \text{ if and only if, for all } i \in I \text{, } x \wedge a (i) \le y (i)$$
In particular, if $h : A \to A'$ is an isomorphism, then:

$\top_A = \bigvee_{i \in I} a (i)$ (by taking $x = \top_A$ and $y = a$).

For all $(k, i) \in I \times I$, $a (k) \wedge a (i) = \bigvee_{j \in \{ k \} \cap \{ i \}} a (j)$ (by taking $x = a (k)$ and $y (i) = \bigvee_{j \in \{ k \} \cap \{ i \}} a (j)$).


Conversely:

If $\top_A = \bigvee_{i \in I} a (i)$, then $h : A \to A'$ is injective.

If for all $(k, i) \in I \times I$, $a (k) \wedge a (i) = \bigvee_{j \in \{ k \} \cap \{ i \}} a (j)$, then $h : A \to A'$ is surjective:


$$\begin{aligned}
a (i) \wedge \bigvee_{j \in I} y (j)
& = \bigvee_{j \in I} (a (i) \wedge y (j)) \\
& = \bigvee_{j \in I} ((a (i) \wedge a (j)) \wedge y (j)) \\
& = \bigvee_{j \in I} \left( y (j) \wedge \bigvee_{k \in \{ i \} \cap \{ j \}} a (k) \right) \\
& = \bigvee_{j \in I} \bigvee_{k \in \{ i \} \cap \{ j \}} (a (k) \wedge y (j)) \\
& = \bigvee_{k \in \{ i \}} \bigvee_{j \in \{ i \}} (a (k) \wedge y (j)) \\
& = a (i) \wedge y (i) = y (i)
\end{aligned}$$
Thus, we obtain an "elementary" characterisation of when $h : A \to A'$ is an isomorphism, and this characterisation is clearly preserved by frame homomorphisms as desired.
